# ndarray array2string output format

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I know this is a simple question, but can only find part of the answer on SO, and can't figure out how to do from Python or Numpy documentation. I'm sure it's documented, I just don't understand.

I need to print/write using a fixed format (6 fields at 13.7e). The array I need to print might have 4, 8, 12, or more values. I found `np.array2string`, which is **almost** what I need.

- Is there a way to eliminate the leading and trailing `[` and `]`?
- Likewise, is there a way to avoid the indentation on 2nd and
  following lines?

Solution does not have to use `array2string`. It was the simplest thing I found to control print/write formatting for `ndarray`. I am open to any solution. :-)

Here is my a simple example to demonstrate behavior I want, and what I get:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> foo = np.arange(4.0)
>>> # this shows desired output with 4 values
>>> print( ('%13.7e'*4) % (foo[0], foo[1], foo[2], foo[3]) )
0.0000000e+001.0000000e+002.0000000e+003.0000000e+00
>>> print ( np.array2string(foo, separator='', formatter={'float_kind':'{:13.7e}'.format}) )
[0.0000000e+001.0000000e+002.0000000e+003.0000000e+00]
>>> foo = np.arange(12.0)
>>> print ( np.array2string(foo, separator='', max_line_width=80, formatter={'float_kind':'{:13.7e}'.format}) )
[0.0000000e+001.0000000e+002.0000000e+003.0000000e+004.0000000e+005.0000000e+00
 6.0000000e+007.0000000e+008.0000000e+009.0000000e+001.0000000e+011.1000000e+01]
>>> # this shows desired output with 12 values
>>> print( ('%13.7e'*6) % (foo[0], foo[1], foo[2], foo[3], foo[4], foo[5]) )
0.0000000e+001.0000000e+002.0000000e+003.0000000e+004.0000000e+005.0000000e+00
>>> print( ('%13.7e'*6) % (foo[6], foo[7], foo[8], foo[9], foo[10], foo[11]) )
6.0000000e+007.0000000e+008.0000000e+009.0000000e+001.0000000e+011.1000000e+01
```

Comment: `np.savetxt` does a formatted write just like what you want.  It iterates on rows (of a 2d array), formats with `fmt % tuple(row)`, where `fmt` is constructed as you do with a string repeat.  I don't think it's worth fiddling with `array2string`.

Comment: @hpaulj. Thanks, I looked at `np.savetxt`, but couldn't figure out how to append to the savetext file. I need to do this write several times in the course of the routine, appending each time. I left that out of the problem statement. Sorry.

Comment: You can give `savetxt` a file you opened yourself.

Comment: @hpaulj, ok, I will investigate how to do that. Thanks.

Comment: @hpaulj, I'm so close I can almost taste it, but stuck on one issue. I used `np.savetxt(file1, foo, delimiter='', fmt='%13.7e')`, and get one array item per line. Close, but I need 6 per line (or less as the list is depleted). If I modify to `np.savetxt(file1, foo, delimiter='', fmt=('%13.7e'*6) )`, I get this error: `ValueError: fmt has wrong number of % formats:  %13.7e%13.7e%13.7e%13.7e%13.7e%13.7e`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @hpaulj, ok, I figured out part of my problem. I get single values b/c the shape of foo is (12,1) and I need 1 row, and many columns. When I use `reshape(1,12)`, I get all 12 values on a row. And, I can use `reshape(2,6)` to get 2 rows of 6. All very good. However, what if I have 9, or 15 or some other number of values that is not a multiple of 6 (so won't `reshape`)? `array2string` looks like the simpler approach for my situation IMHO.

Comment: I realize that with ragged lines like yours, `savetxt` doesn't work.  It's meant for `csv` files, and the loaders for such files have problems with variable length lines (especially with '' delimiter).  But I mentioned `savetxt` more to show that your `(fmt*n)%tuple(row)` approach is ok.  But you'd have to figure out for yourself how to break the array into blocks that may vary in length.

Comment: @hpaulj, yeah, I could create a `while` loop to manage the output. However, for this particular usage `np.array2string` seems a better choice than `np.savetxt`. This was still a good use of tme; `np.savetxt` will be very handy when I want to output the entire array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of `np.array2string` is just a string.  You can format it using normal string methods.  For instance, you can strip off the lead/tail brackets and replace spaces with nothing using:

```
foo = np.arange(12.)
s = (np.array2string(foo, 
         separator='', 
         formatter={'float_kind':'{:13.7e}'.format}, 
         max_line_width=80).strip('[]').replace(' ', ''))
print(s)
# prints:
0.0000000e+001.0000000e+002.0000000e+003.0000000e+004.0000000e+005.0000000e+00
6.0000000e+007.0000000e+008.0000000e+009.0000000e+001.0000000e+011.1000000e+01
```

Comment: Thanks. There you go...just add a couple of string manipulations. :-)